# Pulling data for each month SQL even if there is no data

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a graph of the sum of one MySQL column over the past few months. Right now I have the SQL statement:

```
SELECT SUM(Distance) AS `Data`, MONTH(`Date`) AS `DateVal` 
FROM `Activities` 
WHERE Date > ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -10 MONTH) GROUP BY YEAR(`Date`), 
   MONTH(`Date`) ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 10
```

This SQL statement does not work because it only pulls out the months that have data. Is there a way for the SQL server to return 0 for months that have no data?

The only I could find to do this would be to use 10 different queries, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is possible that some months have no dates, you have to get the list of months from somewhere: To do that, you need a table with the list of months, and then join that table in your query. This way, all months with no data will have 0 as value.

```
CREATE TABLE months (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO months VALUES
(1, 'january'), (2, 'february'), (3, 'march'),
(4, 'april'), (5, 'may'), (6, 'june'),
(7, 'july'), (8, 'august'), (9, 'september'),
(10, 'october'), (11, 'november'), (12, 'december');

SELECT SUM(Distance) AS `Data`, MONTH(`Date`) AS `DateVal` 
FROM `Activities` JOIN months on MONTH(`Date`) = months.`id`
WHERE Date > ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -10 MONTH) GROUP BY YEAR(`Date`), 
MONTH(`Date`) ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 10
```